# Cycling through XML and return to start using buttons - AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to create a small app that cycles through an XML document on the press of a button (next or back). So far, I have it cycling through and bringing the information in ok. When it reaches the last record in the XML and you hit the next button, I want it to show the first record. It is currently doing that, however you have to press the button twice. It is only a small XML file, with 5 records.

This is Actionscript 3, by the way.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var myXML:XML;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;

myLoader.load(new URLRequest("book.xml"));

myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

var i:int;
i = 0;

function processXML(e:Event):void
{
    myXML = new XML(e.target.data);

    txtTitle.text = myXML.film.title[i];
    txtReviewScore.text = myXML.film.rating[i];
}

btnNext.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, moveNext);
function moveNext(event:MouseEvent)
{
    if (i == 5)

    {
        i = 0
    }

    else

    i = i + 1;
    txtTitle.text = myXML.film.title[i];
    txtReviewScore.text = myXML.film.rating[i];
}

btnPrevious.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, movePrevious);
function movePrevious(event:MouseEvent)
{   

    if (i == 0)
    {
        i = 5
    }

    else

    i = i - 1;
    txtTitle.text = myXML.film.title[i];
    txtReviewScore.text = myXML.film.rating[i];
}
```

Hope this makes sense, if I need to explain it more I'll do my best.

Cheers

Comment: Where are you getting the number 5 from? I assume this is the number of records, but it may make more sense to grab that info from the `XML` document instead of hard-coding the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're waiting until `i == 5` before attempting to loop around (hence the need to press the next button twice. Since you are dealing with a zero-indexed list of elements, you'll actually be at the last element when `i == 4` (your elements are numbered 0, 1, 2, 3, 4).

If all you change is `i == 5` to `i == 4`, this should work as intended, however, as I mentioned in my comment above, you shouldn't hard-code this number. You should grab it from the XML like so:

```
function moveNext(event:MouseEvent)
{
    if (i == myXML.film.length()-1)

    {
        i = 0;
    }

    else

    i = i + 1;
    txtTitle.text = myXML.film.title[i];
    txtReviewScore.text = myXML.film.rating[i];
}
```

This will make it so that if your `XML` changes and all of a sudden has more or less than 5 records, the code will still work.

**Edit to respond to OP's comment:**

Since you're decrementing `i` right before using it as an index, you wouldn't want to reset it to `length-1`. Instead, you would just set it to `length`:

```
function movePrevious(event:MouseEvent)
{   

    if (i == 0)
    {
        i = myXML.film.length();
    }

    else

    i = i - 1;
    txtTitle.text = myXML.film.title[i];
    txtReviewScore.text = myXML.film.rating[i];
}
```

Comment: Hi @Marcela - many thanks for your response. The next button is working a treat, and thank you for introducing me to the proper use of .length attribute.

I've been trying to do the same with the previous button (so when you get to the first record, it jumps back to the last record) however I'm not sure how this works?

I understand that length()-1 refers to no record being found, and that i=0 sends it to the very first record, but how to you hard code it to jump to the last record?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the corrected `movePrevious` method using the `length` method.

Comment: Many thanks @Marcela. Improved my understanding of Actionscript! :)